# reverse order of list

Tags: javascript, css

```css
div > div {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background: black;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

div.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4">1</div>
  <div class="col-4">2</div>
  <div class="col-4">3</div>
  <div class="col-4">4</div>
  <div class="col-4">5</div>
  <div class="col-4">6</div>
  <div class="col-4">7</div>
</div>
```

i want to reverse this list of numbers to become

```
7  6  5
4  3  2
1
```

i tried using

```
div.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse
}
```

but did not work as i wanted it to be

is it possible to do that using css only?

Comment: `transform: rotate(180deg);` on the parent and `transform: rotate(-180deg);` on the child divs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know you're asking a pure CSS solution, but because that is so easy to achieve using Javascript, I wanted to add that solution as well. Might also be helpful for future readers for whom Javascript is an option.

Also, at this point in time, I believe this cannot be done using CSS only. The additional benefit of using Javascript is that the elements' source order stays consistent with their visual order, which helps alot with accessibility.

```js
function reverseChildren(el) {
  [...el.children].reverse().forEach(child => el.appendChild(child));
}
```

```css
div > div {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background: black;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

div.row {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row" id="row">
  <div class="col-4">1</div>
  <div class="col-4">2</div>
  <div class="col-4">3</div>
  <div class="col-4">4</div>
  <div class="col-4">5</div>
  <div class="col-4">6</div>
  <div class="col-4">7</div>
</div>

<button type="button" onclick="reverseChildren(document.getElementById('row'))">Reverse order</button>
```

So let's try how this performs with 1000 divs:

```js
const row = document.querySelector('.row');
const fragment = new DocumentFragment();

for (let i = 1; i<=1000; i++) {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.className = "col-4";
  div.textContent = i;
  fragment.appendChild(div);
}

row.appendChild(fragment);

function reverseChildren(el) {
  const fragment = new DocumentFragment();
  [...el.children].reverse().forEach(child => {
    el.removeChild(child);
    fragment.appendChild(child);
  })
  el.appendChild(fragment);
}
```

```css
div > div {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background: black;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

div.row {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button type="button" onclick="reverseChildren(document.getElementById('row'))">Reverse order</button>
<div class="row" id="row"></div>
<button type="button" onclick="reverseChildren(document.getElementById('row'))">Reverse order</button>
```

In the second example I modified the `reverseChildren` function to work with a `DocumentFragment`, which is meant to help with performance.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using bootstrap 4, you can use [order](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/#order) classes to specify order of the div.

Example:

```css
div > div {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background: black;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4 order-7">1</div>
  <div class="col-4 order-6">2</div>
  <div class="col-4 order-5">3</div>
  <div class="col-4 order-4">4</div>
  <div class="col-4 order-3">5</div>
  <div class="col-4 order-2">6</div>
  <div class="col-4 order-1">7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: the list can go up to 1000 i think it would be a lot to handle adding classes to order-1000 and i am looking for a quick dynamic way

Answer (score 0):

I think a pure css way to do this would be:

```
div.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There is another css property to order element the ways you want, is order:

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_order.asp

But this is good option only if you know exact number of nodes you will have, I guess.